# Should i be using gradle for continuous deployment?

Tags: continuous-deployment

anyone has past experience with gradle? i'm thinking of using it for continuous deployment... i'm considering either using my own scripts (python) or gradle.

can anyone tell from experience which way he thinks recommanded to go? note i already use maven and i don't intend to move away for my dependency management and project management.

thanks

Comment: i thought also over puppet... what do you say?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have implemented Gradle-based deployment and environment management in a big governmental project (100+ servers). But we had to develop a custom set of plugins (which is actually rather straight forward process in Gradle) to handle tasks like remote SSH command execution through Groovy DSL, creation of application server domains/clusters (we are using WebLogic), application/configuration deployment.

We also are thinking of integrating Gradle with Puppet for easier Linux administration.

If you are coming from Java world, then using Gradle (which is Groovy-based) would be rather simple for you, because you can reuse your Java/Ant/Maven/Groovy knowledge to write scripts. Also an ability to create DSLs in Groovy may allow you to build interesting abstractions. Gradle also has very clean API which allows building nice dependencies between tasks. It also integrates very well with Maven infrastructure and you can reuse all Ant tasks.

Comment: which responsibilities do you give to gradle scripts and which to puppet scripts if i may ask?

Comment: Gradle is used mostly for "operational" tasks like deployment, server restarts, cache cleaning etc., Puppet is used for environment "provisioning" to setup all the OS/AS components - just enough to deploy applications.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Gradle-based deployment possible with [gradle-ssh-plugin](https://github.com/int128/gradle-ssh-plugin)

Here is an [article](http://java.dzone.com/articles/replace-your-scripts-gradle) with good usage example.

Comment: You can also take a look at: https://github.com/aestasit/sshoogr and https://github.com/aestasit/sshoogr-gradle